# Why do I get different answers from this matrix equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

the equation given is $A=(AX+B)^{-1}$, I first multiply by $(AX+B)$ and this yields that $A(AX+B)=I$ I distribute A, $A^2X+AB=I \implies A^2X=I-AB \implies X=(A^2)^{-1}(I-AB)$ If I know try and solve what $(I-AB)$ is, lets say it is C and then compute $A^{-1}$ and compute $(A^{-1})^2$ and then finally compute $(A^{-1})^2 \cdot C$ I get the wrong answer. If I however continue to simplify from this point:$ X=(A^2)^{-1}(I-AB) \implies X=A^{-1}(A^{-1}-B)$ from here I now get the correct answer, how come?

$A=\big(\begin{smallmatrix}
  3 & 2\\
  1 & 1
\end{smallmatrix}\big)$ and $B=\big(\begin{smallmatrix}
  2 & 0\\
  1 & 3
\end{smallmatrix}\big)$ If I compute $(A^2)^{-1}(I-AB)$ I get $X=\big(\begin{smallmatrix}
  0 & -30\\
  0 & 41
\end{smallmatrix}\big)$ and$ A^{-1}(A^{-1}-B) $ gives $ X=\big(\begin{smallmatrix}
  3 & -2\\
  -5 & 2
\end{smallmatrix}\big)$ which is the correct answer.

Comment: This cannot happen and means only that you made an error (for example in computation of $A^2$).

Comment: Check the case with $(A^2)^{-1}$. My computation show that $X$ should be as in the second case.

Comment: You are right, not sure why but for some stupid reason I computed (I-A-B) which is obviously not the same as (I-AB).. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $A^2$ you should have $$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    11 & 8 \\
    4 & 3 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
and for $(A^2)^{-1}$ you should have $$
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & -8 \\
-4 & 11 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
And you should have the correct answer either way.

Comment: I just realized that for some reason I did I-(A-B), no wonder I got two different answers.. Thanks for the help! :)